# How to show the time a user left a page

Tags: yii

I have a simple page tracking system in my Yii app. When a user views a individual item, I update the DB with the `page_id`, `session_id`, `time`. I also have a `time_ended` column though, I'm not sure what the easiest way to update this field would be?

Currently it's very simple like so:

```
public function actionView($id) { // View a single item

// Load item
$model = Item::model()->loadItem($id); 

// load viewed item model
$viewedPage = new ViewedItem;
// set attributes
$viewedPage->page_id = $model->id;
$viewedPage->session_id = Yii::app()->session->sessionId;
$viewedPage->time_started = new CDbExpression('NOW()'); 
$viewedPage->save();

$this->render('view', array(
        'model' => $this->loadModel($id, 'Item'),
}
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Thanks

Jonny

Comment: you need to post the code for whole controller, if you can i may help you. I need to see how you call up model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HTTP is a stateless protocol we can't get sure when user leave a page. But there are two way to do that.

1. Javascript method:
   The event "onbeforeunload" is triggered when user leaves a page. you can look for that event and then use $.post() or $.ajax() to execute a action which will update `$time_ended` for that current `session_id`.
2. Yii Method(Code): There can be a script in server side that will check for each session. it will check that if last request from a `session_id` is `x_second` old then we can set last time recorded as `$time_ended`

I think any of this will be useful.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into this more